# How To Add Multiple Stored Procedures to Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I'm new to using stored procedures. I have two stored procedures and the data of those two procedures is not related to each other. I want show the all data from those two stored procedures in one crystal reports. And also I want to display the data from two procedures one after the other, like below. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
Position History Table
--------------------------------------------------
Date | Grade | Designation | Department | Reason |
--------------------------------------------------



Salary History Table
-------------------------------------
Date | Salary | Salary Change Reason|
-------------------------------------
```

Comment: Use a subreport for the second set of data.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to work with multiple "unrelated" datasets in Crystal is to use sub-reports.